# store.loadData not defined. How to load data into store Sencha Architect

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

In the past, I created my stores using Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', ...
and when I wanted to load data the was contained in a JSON loaded object, all I needed to do was MyStore.loadData(myDataObj);

This does not work with the stores you define in Sencha Architect, you get Not defined error for loadData.

I have a custom Ext.Ajax routine I use to get the data that does not lend itself to being defined in a stores proxy. My data is in the proper JSON format, but I have had no luck finding a way to force load data into a store without using a store proxy.

I was able to get MyStore.add({--json string ...}) to work, but this only adds a single record.

Why is store.loadData() not suppored ???  What can I use instead???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use store.setData assuming you are using a Touch project.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the Sencha API docs. The issue here is that the Store.loadData does not appear to be valid (ie Un-defined) when referenced in a user defined function in Sencha Architect. I have not been able to find a way to take a variable that has a valid JSON object and load it into s store. The only method I believe would work is if I created the stores in a function, but that would defeat the awesome UI the architect provides.